# Building shared object for Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, cmake

I'm currently migrating projects from Ant/ndk-build to Gradle/CMake. I'm not compiling from Android Studio but from the command line. I've already successfully migrated a larger project to Gradle. But now I need to migrate some library projects whose end product is just a shared object, not a complete APK.

So I'm wondering what is the best way to compile Android projects which do not result in an APK but just in a shared object? Gradle looks like it will always compile APKs for me but I don't need that in this case. So should I just use CMake as described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html)? But that looks rather complicated because I'd have to pass all kinds of internal paths which probably change with every SDK/NDK update to CMake which Gradle would probably manage automatically for me.

So what is the best way to compile shared objects for Android from the command line without using Android Studio? Is there maybe a way to put Gradle into library mode so that it doesn't assemble APKs?

Comment: "Gradle looks like it will always compile APKs for me but I don't need that in this case" -- no. Gradle compiles what you tell it to compile, via Gradle plugins. "Is there maybe a way to put Gradle into library mode" -- there are Android library modules, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html.

Comment: Ok, but is there a plugin that was specifically designed to just compile shared objects or how should I go about here? The Android library plugin you linked to isn't helpful here because it creates AAR files which I don't want. I just want to compile a bunch of *.c files into a shared object with no additional actions taking place.

Comment: "I just want to compile a bunch of *.c files into a shared object with no additional actions taking place" -- the modern Android pattern is to create an AAR that contains those shared objects (along with any JNI code to use them), so that the AAR can be put into an artifact repository with suitable metadata (e.g., versioning information, transitive dependencies). If that is not what you want, that is your choice, but AFAIK Android Studio does not support what you want, and I do not have a recipe for doing it with Gradle.

Comment: Well, in that case I could of course just create an AAR and then grab those shared objects from the AAR and dump the rest. I'll check if that's a viable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `gradlew buildNative` from your project's root directory. That will build your *.c files. This is just a wrapper to the NDK, so it would produce the same output as running `ndk-build` from your `app/src/main/jni` directory.

This is assuming that you have your source files, header files, and makefiles in `app/src/main/jni`. The result will be your *.so files.

Comment: Ok, but this still leaves me dependent on `ndk-build`, right? Optimally, I'd like to have a solution that only uses Gradle and CMake and no `ndk-build`.

Comment: Using `ndk-build`, yes. But I think if you use CMake and run `gradle buildNative` that it would just wrap the CMake scripts and produce your .so files. I used the same [CMake link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake.html) you mentioned in your post to build an Android project a few weeks ago. It's a good guide.